# String and int concatination

Tags: c++, string, client-server, fgets

I have to concatenate the output of `fgets` to an `int` (`clientid`), and store this in a `char[1024]` buffer.

Here's my code:

```
clientid = rand() % 256;



while(1)
{
    cout<<"Client: Enter Data for Client=";

    fgets(buffer,MAXSIZE-1,stdin);

    if((send(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer),0))==-1)
    {
        cout<<"Failure Sending Message";
        close(sockfd);
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Client:Message being sent:"<<buffer;
        num=recv(sockfd,buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
        if(num<=0)
        {
            cout<<"either connection close or Error";
            break;
        }
        buffer[num]='\0';
        cout<<"Client:message received from Server:"<<buffer<<endl;
    }
}

close(sockfd);
return 0;
```

How can I extract the `clientid` from the message on the server side?

Comment: one suggestion start using std::string...will surely save lots of effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the beginning of the buffer itself. For example if your clientid is 123 then you can send "123:Message" where ":" can act as a separator. This means you should be reading those many numbers ahead in buffer, instead of from the beginning.

```
snprintf (buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%d:", clientid); // Add the clientid at the beginning before reading 
fgets(buffer + strlen (buffer),MAXSIZE-1,stdin);// Move by the len of buffer which contains clientid
```

Comment: thanks it is working...Will u pls tell me how to identify clientid from total message at server side?

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the message with the clientId by using the strcat() method as follows,

```
 strcat(buffer, clientid);
```

At the server side, you can identify the clientid by selecting the substring from the buffer as follows,

```
  std::string str=buffer;

  std::string str2 = str.substr (messagelength,lastindex);
```